# ping to web server from iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an aplication which needs to download some data from webserver.So i need to first ping to the web server to check whether the service is available after checking the internet connectivity .I used the following code to check server availability

```
BOOL success = NO;
const char *host_name = [@"http://192.168.1.7:8080/TestWeb/webresources/"
                             cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL,
                                                                                host_name);
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
BOOL isAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
return isAvailable;
```

where my server is uploaded locally.But this code always return an invalid result,but it works correctly if i gave some exixting sites like google.com.Please let me know whats i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSURLConnection to ping the server. If the connection can't be made, you will get the response in the delegate method connectionDidFailWithError.

Check out the Apple documentation, they have a good code example:
[link text](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)